# Generate C# Client from OpenApi.json

Tags: c#

I have a .net core 2.2 Class Library.

I have installed the VS Studio 2017 "OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Service" extension.

[image]

I have attempted to use this extension to generate a c# client for the following API:

https://skybox.vividseats.com/services/openapi.json

The extension runs and builds a number of files:

[image]

But, when I build the project I have 1640 errors:

[image]

It appears to have generated all the functions and named then as 1Async, 2Async etc....

[image]

Can anyone see anything wrong that I am doing? Or suggest another method to generate a client from the url?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may want to try [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate C# .NET Core client:

Download latest stable version v4.1.3: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/4.1.3/openapi-generator-cli-4.1.3.jar, and rename it as openapi-generator-cli.jar

> java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://skybox.vividseats.com/services/openapi.json -o /var/tmp/ --skip-validate-spec

I can build the project without issue. Please test it to see if it works for you.

There are spec validation errors so I use  `--skip-validate-spec` to skip those errors. Please review those errors when you've time.

There are other ways to install OpenAPI Generator: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#1---installation

UPDATE: we've added a `csharp-netcore` client generator. Please check out the latest master of v5.0.0 release to give it a try.

UPDATE: `csharp-netcore` has been renamed to `csharp` in v7.0.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution to this problem.

The solution is to define `OperationId` for every endpoint.
You can do this in different ways, I think it's the best described [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#assign-explicit-operationids).

I do this in the `SwaggerDefaultValues`:

```cs
var controllerActionDescriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)apiDescription.ActionDescriptor;
var controllerName = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
var actionName = controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName;
operation.OperationId ??= $"{controllerName}{actionName}";
```

It's **important** to note that operation id SHOULD NOT contain underscores.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
Able to solve this by using `NSwagStudio` and set the

> `"operationGenerationMode": "SingleClientFromOperationId"`

I faced similar issue while generating C# client from API that have operationId with name_[number] format.

I do believe it's a bug on the generator as it generates invalid method name.
Though I much prefer to rename the operationId with more meaningful name instead of using number; though it requires to have control on the API that you're trying to consume / generate client.

credit:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/934